# The value of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \exp(-a n^2) n^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the value of

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \exp(-a n^2) n^k$

where $a>0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k >0 \in \mathbb{N}\cup 0$. This series is always convergent by the ratio test.

**edit:**

Is there an upperbound for this series?

Comment: For $k=0$ you will find some values here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function

Answer (score 5):

I think that there is no explicit expression for this value.

Nevertheless, you can try to approximate it by [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \exp(-a n^2) n^k \approx 
\int\limits_{0}^\infty \exp(-a x^2) x^k\,dx = \bigg/\sqrt{a}x = t~\bigg/ =
\frac1{a^{(k+1)/2}}\int\limits_{0}^\infty \exp(-t^2) t^k\,dt =
$$
$$
= 
\bigg/t^2~=~z~\bigg/ = \frac1{2a^{(k+1)/2}}\int\limits_{0}^\infty \exp(-z) z^{(k-1)/2}\,dz = \frac1{2a^{(k+1)/2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right),
$$
where $\Gamma(y)$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: Is there an upperbound known to this series?